# Bug Report in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have found a bug in SPSS 23 which isn't fixed with Fixpack2. I'd like to file this bug but I didn't find a way to do so on the ibm support page.

What is the recommended way to file a SPSS bug report?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bug you probably want to report it to `Technical Support`, you should have an account with IBM to access this or register otherwise with your contract number/information, providing you have valid support contract.

There is also `Request for Enhancement`, not quite bug related, but any requests for advancements in the software that you might desire to see in future release can be put forward on this platform.

Both can be found easily via search engines (providing a link might become outdated).